# Gutenberg list items nesting and creating invalid content errors

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to figure out why Gutenberg is creating nested lists instead of adding to the existing list, basically when the list block is selected I am able to make a single li element and then when trying to add another li element it creates a whole list nested in the first li element. Also pressing enter after creating the first li element has no effect, I would expect the action of pressing enter while creating a list would generate a new li element?

[image]

When I try to edit the block via HTML and manually add another li element it breaks the block and claims the content is invalid, an option to "attempt block recovery" is displayed but does not actually do anything or recover anything.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this issue? Is Gutenberg really this broken ( still )?

Comment: If I add a list block, start typing and then press Enter I get a new list item, as expected. If I press the + button it will add a new list. If you're not seeing that behaviour try disabling plugins and themes to see if that helps.

Comment: As @Jacob Peattie wrote, inserting a block with inserter does nest a new list inside existing list. To continue the list instead of nesting, type enter key after end of each list item

Comment: If this behaviour is not intuitive, you can open issue on Gutenberg github and if it collects enough upvotes, it can be changed. When I first encountered that, it was also counterintuitive for me. If you open an issue, I'll give you a vote :)

Comment: And you cannot just enter <li>...</li> manually, since block content also contains block metadata, so you should encode entire block, not just block's html. You can enter block editing in text mode and copy the whole block if you wish. However, it looks that something is broken in your installation or some plugin changes default behaviour, pressing enter at the end of the list element should start new list element.

Comment: If nothing else succeeds, you can press unindent button (fourth from left) in block toolbar on your image.

Comment: Yeah there's a conflict in the theme somewhere causing the issue, switching to a default WP theme the behavior is as expected. Still haven't figured out the issue exactly but was just curious if anyone observed this behavior before. thanks.